# Using QuikGraph and GraphX to show graph on visual studio C# form

Tags: c#, quickgraph, graphx-net

I want to create a Visual Studio C# console application that allows me to render certain graphs to the form and let the user manipulate them.

I plan to use QuikGraph as a library to manage my graph and use [GraphX](https://github.com/panthernet/GraphX) for rendering.
It says that this combination can be used, but I cannot find a user-friendly/simple example that I can use as a reference.

I have searched through the documentation and online, but couldn't find anything.

Does anyone have a simple example that I can use to render a graph to a Visual Studio C# form with these libraries?

Comment: The library is designed for a WPF application.  Are you using WPF or Windows Form.  Library is only for WPF.  A Form is a control and your link does show example code for a control.